# Join with Max and pre-Max row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, max

I have two tables 'sites' and 'index_log'. Table 'sites' is a information about sites(userid, name, description ...) Table index_log have columns date, index_count and siteid. So I want to get last and previous index_log row for each site, where userid = 10. This's my variant:

```
 SELECT ff.id,
        ff.siteurl,
        ff.last_count,
        ff.last_date,
        il2.index_count as previous_count,
        MAX(il2.date) as previous_date
FROM (
    SELECT s.siteurl,
            s.id,
            il.index_count as last_count,
            MAX(il.date) as last_date
    FROM sites s 
    LEFT JOIN index_logs il ON il.siteid = s.id
    WHERE s.userid = 10
    GROUP BY s.id
    ) as ff
LEFT JOIN index_logs il2 ON il2.siteid = ff.id AND il2.date < ff.last_date
GROUP BY ff.id
```

But in this variant index_count column(last and previous) do not match with max date row. I hope for your help.

Comment: This is no valid SQL Server query, looks like mysql?

Comment: What makes you says that @dnoeth ?

Comment: `GROUP BY` doesn't include all those non-aggregated columns in the SELECT list...

Comment: MS SQL does not allowed that. You mean it is allow in MySQL ?

Comment: @Squirrel: Yep, that's done a lot in mysql (returning some random row) and when they switch to any other DBMS they wonder why it's not working anymore?

Comment: i see. I just assumed that OP query is in-complete and can't get it work, that's why it is posted here for help

Comment: It's mysql. Sorry, I made a mistake in tags.

Answer (score 0):

this will gives you last 2 log entries per sites.id

```
; with CTE as
(
    SELECT s.siteurl, s.id, il.index_count, il.date, 
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY il.date DESC)
    FROM   sites s
    JOIN   index_logs il ON il.siteid = s.id
    WHERE  s.userid = 10
)
SELECT *
FROM   CTE
WHERE  RN <= 2
```

Comment: i have no idea that you are using MySQL

Comment: Does MySQL has a similar function like ROW_NUMBER() ?

Comment: No it haven't, the main problem was with 'with', but it already not a problem, I used php filtration for full join.

Comment: And thanks for your help! Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to put you plus.